# Laravel 4.2 Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)

Tags: php, laravel-4.2

I have able to see my login page but when logged in with proper username/password it shows below error message.

[2018-09-22 09:04:12] production.ERROR: PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO) in /var/www/html/recruitment/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connectors/Connector.php:47
Stack trace:

## 0 /var/www/html/recruitment/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connectors/Connector.php(47): PDO->__construct('mysql:host=loca...', 'root', '', Array)

## 1 /var/www/html/recruitment/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connectors/MySqlConnector.php(20): Illuminate\Database\Connectors\Connector->createConnection('mysql:host=loca...', Array, Array)

Please help me.

Comment: database connection username and password valid. I have able to logged that db username and password from command line.

Comment: you need to configure this user and give mu access to connection from localhost (you can use widlcard %) (command-line connection is not the same)